# I'll pretend I didn't see it/not to have seen it?

Tags: expressions, grammaticality-in-context

Someone sent me a message and I saw it but I didn't want to talk about it so I said:
*"I'll pretend **not to have** seen it."*

I've heard people say 'I'll pretend I didn't see it.' I just want to know what 'not to have' means here or if it's even correct as I said it subconsciously without even knowing if it's correct.

Comment: In speech, the first is better. In a description of someone's speech, the second is fine. But I wouldn't say it.

Comment: I would quite happily say "I'll pretend not to have (something)". Quite normal in British speech or writing. I farted at the palace but the Queen pretended not to have noticed.